# What is an electric unicorn?

Tags: discussion, chat, fun, unicorns

The About of the [SE chat bot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/stack-exchange) writes:

> I'm just a bot. Sometimes I post feed items, sometimes I post room status changes, sometimes I dream about electric unicorns.

I'm not a native speaker so I don't get the metaphor of the electric unicorn. What does it mean? Why does the bot dream about it? A quick google doesn't give me any useful information.

Comment: from Worldbuilding: [How do I explain a unicorn discharging powerful electricity at a distance?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/109199/4914)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A few things here...

One is the Unicorns reference - it is a [Stack Exchange meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/140505). We love [unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/140505).

The other is a play on the science fiction book that lead to the motion film [Blade Runner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner) - the original title is ["Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Androids_Dream_of_Electric_Sheep%3F).

Since a bot can be seen to be an "android" (albeit without a body), and with our love for unicorns, you get the "sometimes I dream about electric unicorns".

Ruined the joke for anyone?

Comment: Note how dreams of unicorns also play an important role in *Blade Runner.*

Comment: I'd like to highlight that it's not a simple sci-fi book, respects shall be payed when talking about Philip K. Dick's work :)

Comment: Please hide this from Marvel/DC otherwise they will make a superhero out of it.